# How to add a new additional dash and launcher in Unity. (beside of current launcher)

Tags: unity

Is there any way to add a new launcher or application list like current one?

I mean, I have many installed applications, and I wanna have them all, in 2 panels.

Please help me how to do that!

-- I'm using Natty.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable the gnome panels by pressing Alt+F2 and type: gnome-panels

With the gnome panels enabled you still have the launcher panel on the left and the rest of the Unity “looks” but you can also add shortuts and launchers to the top and bottom panel.. just like we can on Ubuntu 10.10

To start the gnome panels without having to enter the command you can create a launcher on your desktop click with your right mouse button on your desktop and select Create Launcher. First enter a name for the launcher and type: gnome-panel in the Command field (You can add a comment if you want). When done cllick on the OK button and the launcher will be shown on your desktop.

Or you can add the command line to the startup list press Alt+F2 and type:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

Your Startup Applications Preferences manager will open now click on the Add button, enter a name and type: gnome-panel in the Command field. Add a comment if you want and click on the OK button. Now the gnome panel will enabled automatically at startup. When using this option the top gnome panel will NOT be shown because the Unity top panel overlaps it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible to have more than one Unity launcher.

However, you can use a dock, which is similar to the launcher. It doesn't have keyboard shortcuts like the launcher but it has many of the other features. I would recommend [Docky](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Welcome_to_the_Docky_wiki) which also has docklets (little mini applications such as weather or timer) and helpers for applications (this adds a quicklist to the application's icon with common options.